# Neural Network: Backpropagation not working (Java)

Tags: java, neural-network, backpropagation

I have to create an OCR Programm for a school project, so I started to create a Backpropagation algorithm with the help of wikipedia. To train my Network, I use the MNIST Database, which I extracted a few days ago, so that I have the real image files. But now the error is always about 237 and after training a while, the error and weights become NaN. What is wrong with my code ?

[A screenshot of my images folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPcpR.png)

Here is my Main class, which shall train my Network:

```
package de.Marcel.NeuralNetwork;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class OCR {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // create network
        NeuralNetwork net = new NeuralNetwork(784, 450, 5, 0.2);

    // load Images
    File file = new File("images");

    int images= 0;
    double error = 0;
    for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(f);

        int t = -1;
        double[] pixels = new double[784];
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
                t++;
                Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));

                if (c.getRed() == 0 && c.getGreen() == 0 && c.getBlue() == 0) {
                    pixels[t] = 1;
                } else if (c.getRed() == 255 && c.getGreen() == 255 && c.getBlue() == 255) {
                    pixels[t] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            if (f.getName().startsWith("1")) {
                net.learn(pixels, new double[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
                error += net.getError();

                images++;
            } else if (f.getName().startsWith("2")) {
                net.learn(pixels, new double[] { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 });
                error += net.getError();

                images++;
            } else if (f.getName().startsWith("3")) {
                net.learn(pixels, new double[] { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 });
                error += net.getError();

                images++;
            } else if (f.getName().startsWith("4")) {
                net.learn(pixels, new double[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 });
                error += net.getError();

                images++;
            } else if (f.getName().startsWith("5")) {
                net.learn(pixels, new double[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 });
                error += net.getError();

                images++;
            } else if (f.getName().startsWith("6")) {
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    error = error / iterations;

    System.out.println("Trained images: " + images);
    System.out.println("Error: " + error);

    //save
    System.out.println("Save");
    try {
        net.saveNetwork("network.nnet");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

... this is my Neuron class:

```
package de.Marcel.NeuralNetwork;

public class Neuron {
    private double input, output;

public Neuron () {

}

public void setInput(double input) {
    this.input = input;
}

public void setOutput(double output) {
    this.output = output;
}

public double getInput() {
    return input;
}

public double getOutput() {
    return output;
}
```

}

... and finally my NeuralNetwork

```
package de.Marcel.NeuralNetwork;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Random;

public class NeuralNetwork {
    private Neuron[] inputNeurons, hiddenNeurons, outputNeurons;
    private double[] weightMatrix1, weightMatrix2;
    private double learningRate, error;

public NeuralNetwork(int inputCount, int hiddenCount, int outputCount, double learningRate) {
    this.learningRate = learningRate;

    // create Neurons
    // create Input
    this.inputNeurons = new Neuron[inputCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputCount; i++) {
        this.inputNeurons[i] = new Neuron();
    }
    // createHidden
    this.hiddenNeurons = new Neuron[hiddenCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < hiddenCount; i++) {
        this.hiddenNeurons[i] = new Neuron();
    }
    // createOutput
    this.outputNeurons = new Neuron[outputCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < outputCount; i++) {
        this.outputNeurons[i] = new Neuron();
    }

    // create weights
    Random random = new Random();
    // weightMatrix1
    this.weightMatrix1 = new double[inputCount * hiddenCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputCount * hiddenCount; i++) {
        this.weightMatrix1[i] = (random.nextDouble() * 2 - 1) / 0.25;
    }
    // weightMatrix2
    this.weightMatrix2 = new double[hiddenCount * outputCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < hiddenCount * outputCount; i++) {
        this.weightMatrix2[i] = (random.nextDouble() * 2 - 1) / 0.25;
    }
}

public void calculate(double[] input) throws Exception {
    // verfiy input length
    if (input.length == inputNeurons.length) {
        // forwardPropagation
        // set input array as input and output of input neurons
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            inputNeurons[i].setInput(input[i]);
            inputNeurons[i].setOutput(input[i]);
        }

        // calculate output of hiddenNeurons
        for (int h = 0; h < hiddenNeurons.length; h++) {
            Neuron hNeuron = hiddenNeurons[h];
            double totalInput = 0;

            // sum up totalInput of Neuron
            for (int i = 0; i < inputNeurons.length; i++) {
                Neuron iNeuron = inputNeurons[i];
                totalInput += iNeuron.getOutput() * weightMatrix1[h * inputNeurons.length + i];
            }

            // set input
            hNeuron.setInput(totalInput);

            // calculate output by applying sigmoid
            double calculatedOutput = sigmoid(totalInput);

            // set output
            hNeuron.setOutput(calculatedOutput);
        }

        // calculate output of outputNeurons
        for (int o = 0; o < outputNeurons.length; o++) {
            Neuron oNeuron = outputNeurons[o];
            double totalInput = 0;

            // sum up totalInput of Neuron
            for (int h = 0; h < hiddenNeurons.length; h++) {
                Neuron hNeuron = hiddenNeurons[h];
                totalInput += hNeuron.getOutput() * weightMatrix2[o * hiddenNeurons.length + h];
            }

            // set input
            oNeuron.setInput(totalInput);

            // calculate output by applying sigmoid
            double calculatedOutput = sigmoid(totalInput);

            // set output
            oNeuron.setOutput(calculatedOutput);
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception("[NeuralNetwork] input array is either too small or to big");
    }
}

public void learn(double[] input, double[] output) throws Exception {
    double partialOutput = 0;

    // verfiy input length
    if (input.length == inputNeurons.length) {
        // forwardPropagation
        // set input array as input and output of input neurons
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            inputNeurons[i].setInput(input[i]);
            inputNeurons[i].setOutput(input[i]);
        }

        // calculate output of hiddenNeurons
        for (int h = 0; h < hiddenNeurons.length; h++) {
            Neuron hNeuron = hiddenNeurons[h];
            double totalInput = 0;

            // sum up totalInput of Neuron
            for (int i = 0; i < inputNeurons.length; i++) {
                Neuron iNeuron = inputNeurons[i];
                totalInput += iNeuron.getOutput() * weightMatrix1[h * inputNeurons.length + i];
            }

            // set input
            hNeuron.setInput(totalInput);

            // calculate output by applying sigmoid
            double calculatedOutput = sigmoid(totalInput);

            // set output
            hNeuron.setOutput(calculatedOutput);
        }

        // calculate output of outputNeurons
        for (int o = 0; o < outputNeurons.length; o++) {
            Neuron oNeuron = outputNeurons[o];
            double totalInput = 0;

            // sum up totalInput of Neuron
            for (int h = 0; h < hiddenNeurons.length; h++) {
                Neuron hNeuron = hiddenNeurons[h];
                totalInput += hNeuron.getOutput() * weightMatrix2[o * hiddenNeurons.length + h];
            }

            // set input
            oNeuron.setInput(totalInput);

            // calculate output by applying sigmoid
            double calculatedOutput = sigmoid(totalInput);

            // set output
            oNeuron.setOutput(calculatedOutput);
        }

        // backPropagation
        double totalError = 0;
        // calculate weights in matrix2
        for (int h = 0; h < hiddenNeurons.length; h++) {
            Neuron hNeuron = hiddenNeurons[h];

            for (int o = 0; o < outputNeurons.length; o++) {
                Neuron oNeuron = outputNeurons[o];

                // calculate weight
                double delta = learningRate * derivativeSigmoid(oNeuron.getInput())
                        * (output[o] - oNeuron.getOutput()) * hNeuron.getOutput();

                // set new weight
                weightMatrix2[h + o * hiddenNeurons.length] = weightMatrix2[h + o * hiddenNeurons.length] + delta;

                // update partial output
                partialOutput += (derivativeSigmoid(oNeuron.getInput()) * (output[o] - oNeuron.getOutput())
                        * weightMatrix2[h + o * hiddenNeurons.length]);

                //calculate error
                totalError += Math.pow((output[o] - oNeuron.getOutput()), 2);
            }
        }

        //set error
        this.error = 0.5 * totalError;

        // calculate weights in matrix1
        for (int i = 0; i < inputNeurons.length; i++) {
            Neuron iNeuron = inputNeurons[i];

            for (int h = 0; h < hiddenNeurons.length; h++) {
                Neuron hNeuron = hiddenNeurons[h];

                // calculate weight
                double delta = learningRate * derivativeSigmoid(hNeuron.getInput()) * partialOutput
                        * (iNeuron.getOutput());

                // set new weight
                weightMatrix1[i + h * inputNeurons.length] = weightMatrix1[i + h * inputNeurons.length] + delta;
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception("[NeuralNetwork] input array is either too small or to big");
    }
}

// save Network
public void saveNetwork(String fileName) throws Exception {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

    writer.write("weightmatrix1:");
    writer.write(System.lineSeparator());

    // write weightMatrix1
    for (double d : weightMatrix1) {
        writer.write(d + "-");
    }

    writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
    writer.write("weightmatrix2:");
    writer.write(System.lineSeparator());

    // write weightMatrix2
    for (double d : weightMatrix2) {
        writer.write(d + "-");
    }

    // save
    writer.close();
}

// sigmoid function
private double sigmoid(double input) {
    return Math.exp(input * (-1));
}

private double derivativeSigmoid(double input) {
    return sigmoid(input) * (1 - sigmoid(input));
}

public double getError() {
    return error;
}
}
```

Comment: NaN means Not a Number. It occurs when you do division by zero. For example, double error = 10 / 0; error will be equals to NaN. Also if you do double anotherVar = 1 + error; anotherVar will too be NaN.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your sigmoid function is incorrect. It should be 1/(1+exp(-x)).

If you still run into NaN errors, it might be because using the function as such can be an overkill, especially for large numbers (ie, numbers less than -10 and greater than 10).

Using an array of precalculated values of sigmoid(x) might prevent this problem for bigger datasets and will also help the program run more efficiently.

Hope this helps!